# Phalcon Unit Test listener event

Tags: php, unit-testing, events, listener, phalcon

I write a listener to hook event trigger by \Phalcon\Mvc\Application. And my code is below

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventManager;
use Listener\Application as ApplicationListener;

// Create application instance
$application = new Application();
$application->setEventsManager(new EventManager());

// Attach listener to handle events
$application->getEventsManager()
            ->attach("application", new ApplicationListener(), 1000);
```

And below this is my class **Listener\Application**

```
namespace Listener;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception as DispatchException;

class Application
{
    public function boot($event, $application)
    {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

I want to write PHP Unit test for this listener (boot method). Can anyone help me to write example for this situation.

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Event Manager test](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/1.3.0/unit-tests/EventsTest.php) that comes with Phalcon.